# based on uwsim, the orientation z from imu is in the inverval from -0.6 to 0.99, what is the unit of these values

Tags: ros, imu, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

based on uwsim, the orientation z from imu is in the inverval from -0.6 to 0.99, what is the unit of these values. the unit is not degree

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227667/based-on-uwsim,-the-orientation-z-from-imu-is-in-the-inverval-from--0.6-to-0.99,-what-is-the-unit-of-these-values/) by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The IMU is publishing a quaternion from world coordinates to IMU.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0